# I want to change UTC date time stamp to IST date time stamp in online excel

Tags: excel, datetime, excel-formula

"2020-09-01 10:23:38Z" I have date time in this format in a column I want this entire column datetime format changed from UTC to IST
Here are some values:

```
D                                  F
TimeStamp(UTC)                    TimeStamp(IST)
2020-09-01 10:23:38Z              2020-09-01 15:53:38Z        
2020-09-01 10:23:31Z              2020-09-01 15:53:31Z
2020-09-01 10:22:18Z              2020-09-01 15:52:18Z
```

Since IST is 5 hours 30 minutes ahead of UTC every value of column F needs to be ahead of D by 5 hours 30 minutes

Here are the list of things I have tried:

```
=D2+TIME(5,30,0)  
=D2+TIMEVALUE("5:30")  
=D2+5.5/24
=DATE(MID(D2,12,4),MONTH(1&MID(D2,5,3)),MID(D2,9,2))+(-6*3600+MID(D2,17,2)*3600+MID(D2,20,2)*60+MID(D2,23,2))/(24 * 3600)
```

All of the the above leads to #VALUE! error

I want the result to look like F column mentioned in example. I am looking for a formula to do that.

Answer (score 0):

#VALUE error is happening because excel is not recognizing date string which ends with Z.

You can write following formula to exclude the last character and add the time.

```
=LEFT(D2,LEN(D2)-1) +  (5.5/24)
```

This will produce IST date time in floating point format. You can change the format to "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ssZ" to show similar to input. Alternatively you can use following formula, which will produce result in TEXT format.

```
=TEXT(LEFT(D2,LEN(D2)-1) +  (5.5/24), "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ssZ")
```